# ERROR: No logical assign for filename FNAME

Tags: sas

I was running the following code:

```
%LET TIME_INTERVAL='MINUTE15';
/*
 * Get the file names of a specific location
 */
%MACRO get_filenames(location,filenames);
filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
data &filenames(keep=fname);
  handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
  if handle > 0 then do;
    count=dnum(handle);
    do i=1 to count;
      fname=dread(handle,i);
      output &filenames;
    end;
  end;
  rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _dir_ clear;
%MEND;

%MACRO NBBO (fname);
DATA TICKERS_NBBO;
    INFILE &fname;
    INPUT SYMBOL $;
RUN;
%mend;

%MACRO CALCU(DATE_VAR);
%get_filenames('./groups',filenames);
data _null_;
    set filenames;
    by fname;
    if fname =: "&TIME_INTERVAL";
    %NBBO(fname);
run;
%mend;
```

However, I got the error: `ERROR: No logical assign for filename FNAME.`

I was wondering what is the reason that caused this?

There are lots of csv files in the folder `groups`. I was trying to run the NBBO macro on each of the files and load each of the files into a dataset with `infile` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up data step code and macro code in a manner that's not permitted.  You can't extract the contents of the variable `fname` and use it to populate a macro variable in this way.  Instead you're passing the text `fname` to that macro variable, which then doesn't work.

You also can't run another data step inside a data step in this manner.  You need to use one of the various methods for executing it after the data step terminates or during execution.

Finally, it's entirely unclear to me what you're really doing here: because you're going to end up with just one of those files in the dataset.

I *think* you may want something like this, which is much easier.  I use the `FILEVAR` option in `infile`, which uses the value of a variable; I have to make some changes to how you calculate fname (I think you have to do this anyway, it has no directory name in it).

```
%MACRO get_filenames(location,filenames);
filename _dir_ "%bquote(&location.)";
data &filenames(keep=fname);
  length fname $512;
  handle=dopen( '_dir_' );
  if handle > 0 then do;
    count=dnum(handle);
    do i=1 to count;
      fname=catx('\',"%bquote(&location.)",dread(handle,i));
      output &filenames;
    end;
  end;
  rc=dclose(handle);
run;
filename _dir_ clear;
%MEND;

%get_filenames(location=c:\temp\cars, filenames=fnam);

data tickers_nbbo;
  set fnam;
  infile a filevar=fname  dlm=',';
  input symbol $;
run;
```

If you really do need to call a data step separately, you either need to use `CALL EXECUTE`, `DOSUBL`, or construct macro calls in another way (`PROC SQL SELECT INTO`, `%INCLUDE`, etc.).

Comment: Is it possible for me to call Macro NBBO on each of the files in the filenames?

Comment: For example `call execute(cats('%nrstr(%NBBO)(',fname,')'));`

Comment: Yes, it's possible (that is the way you'd use call execute, more or less).  It's not going to do what you want in the above example, though, my example is what you'd want I'm pretty sure (unless your example is not representative).

Comment: Yea I have more code in the NBBO that I want to execute. I want to input a different csv file each time.

Comment: Then you have all sorts of options, `call execute` being one of them.